# how I setting my user and password to SVN Repository in Intellij IDEA 14?

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea, ide, settings

Where I go in Intellij IDEA to setting my user and password of my SVN Repository?

[image]

I go to [IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.0 Web Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/authentication-required.html) and follow the tutorial, but I could not open the window to configure the User and Password.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The documentation is quite terse, but what you're looking for appears to be here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/authentication-required.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey I read this, but I didn't found this dialog.

Comment: It's subtitled `VCS | Browse Subversion Repository`.  Is that a menu/submenu combination?

Comment: Yes, I go to post the screen here.

Comment: Seems we're overlooking something really obvious.

Comment: Sorry @RobertHarvey, I'm beginner with Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem because I unchecked "Use command line client", so I install a command line client and all work fine.

[image]